# how to catch out of memory exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

can anyone please tell me how to catch out of memory exception?

for ex.

```
try
{
    while(true)
    {
        int i = new int;
    }
}
catch( ? <--- what should be put here?)
{
    //exception handling
}
```

and also this,

```
queue<int> q;
try
{
     while(true)
     {
          q.push(10);
     }
}
catch( ? <---- what should be put here?)
{
     //error handling
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exception classes are in the standard C++ library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938979/what-exception-classes-are-in-the-standard-c-library)

Comment: @MooingDuck I think everyone who has this exact question is better served by the answers below than the answers to that question

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Catch [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).

You will also need a strategy for handling the errors, since many of the things you'd like to do will require memory (even if it's only to display an error to the user before shutting down). One strategy is to allocate a block of memory at startup, and `delete` it in the exception handler *before* attempting to use more memory, so that there is some available to use.

Comment: Note that in practical situations some memory might have already been freed by the stack unwinding (destruction of local `std::string` variables for instance) between throwing and catching the error. Typically a handler for `std::bad_alloc` will be fairly "on the outside" of the program, while memory could run out in a deeply nested situation. Just to say that something like printing an error message does not _have to_ fail.

Answer (score 29):

As others have noted, what you want to catch is `std::bad_alloc`. You can also use `catch(...)` or `catch(exception& ex)` to catch any exception; the latter allows the exception data to be read and used in the exception handler.

Mark Ransom had already pointed out that when the program cannot allocate any more memory, even printing an error message may fail. Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    try {
        while(true) {
            // Leaks memory on each iteration as there is no matching delete
            int* a = new int;
            i++;
        }
    } catch(bad_alloc& ex) {
        cerr << sizeof(int) * i << " bytes: Out of memory!";
        cin.get();
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0; // Unreachable
}
```

(*I strongly recommend that the program be compiled as 32-bit to avoid running the system out of memory on a 64-bit machine. 32-bit programs cannot allocate more than 4 GB of memory, or 2 GB by default on Windows.*)

When the first `bad_alloc` gets thrown in the infinite `while` loop, control is passed to the `catch` block, but the program still fails with an unhandled exception. Why? Another `bad_alloc` is thrown *inside the exception handler* while trying to print to `cerr`. You can verify this by using a debugger: Set a breakpoint at the `catch(bad_alloc& ex)` line, run the program in the debugger, then step through each statement once you reach the breakpoint. A `bad_alloc` exception will be thrown in the `cerr` statement.

As such, to properly handle an out-of-memory scenario, you need to set aside some memory so that you can print an error message before exiting. Otherwise, the program will just crash on an unhandled exception while trying to print the error message. To do so, you can allocate a block of memory that is deallocated in the exception handler, as Mark Ransom suggested:

```
// Reserve 16K of memory that can be deleted just in case we run out of memory
char* _emergencyMemory = new char[16384];
// ...
try {
// ...
} catch(bad_alloc& ex) {
    // Delete the reserved memory so we can print an error message before exiting
    delete[] _emergencyMemory;

    cerr << sizeof(int) * i << " bytes: Out of memory!";
    cin.get();
    exit(1);
}
//...
```

Comment: Ever heard about RAII? If you're doing software engineering like this, there is no need to use C++ -- you can use C.

Comment: I've seen people claiming, that the "trick" of pre-allocating memory leads to never running the chance of getting an out-of-memory condition.

Comment: And why would you catch std::bad_alloc as a value?

Comment: Updated the code to catch the exception by reference. However, this code *purposely* avoids RAII because it is specifically intended to leak memory for demonstration purposes. That's the whole point of the answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
catch (std::bad_alloc& ba){
    cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << endl;
}
```

As a note you should read bdonlan's comment.  The call to `cerr` may very well fail.  Mark Ransom's suggestion in his answer is a good strategy to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Note: That print to cerr may fail due to the out-of-memory condition.

Comment: @bdonlan: I agree with you there. I didn't consider that situation, I'm too used to that problem occurring when I try to allocate obscenely large vectors ;).  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @bdonlan: Very slowly after I commented :P

Answer (score 6):

You should `catch` an object of type `std::bad_alloc`.

Alternatively, you can also use a `nothrow` verison of `new` as:

```
int *pi = new (nothrow) int[N]; 
if(pi == NULL) 
{
   std::cout << "Could not allocate memory" << std::endl;
}
```

When you use this, no exception is thrown if the `new` fails. Instead,it simply returns `NULL` which you check before proceeding further.

Comment: Can I somehow set nothrow version of new as default, so I don't need to write `(nothrow)` everytime?

Comment: @Quest: I don't know if that is possible. Maybe, as a last resort, you could do this : `#define NEW new (nothrow)` and then `int *pi = NEW int[N];`.

Comment: I think I've never used this form of new as in my code, successful allocation of memory is not optional.

Comment: @quest for visual c++ link with nothrownew.obj

Comment: @user8434768 Maybe you're working in an environment when you can't afford to throw exceptions due to runtime overhead, or space constraints as for every function that can throw compiler needs to generate additional code.