# C++ : What shall it be returned when out of memory?

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, nothrow

When I code as below, it'll return 'null' and no exception occured.

```
Char* pStr = new(std::nothrow)Char(10);
```

What about not using 'nothrow' argument on new operator?
Does it also returns 'null'? If so, why is it recommended to use 'nothrow' argument?

```
Char* pStr = new Char(10);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [`std::bad_alloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749066/how-to-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-c)

Comment: Who recommended using `nothrow`? http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill16.htm  Avoid using nothrow.

Comment: Where is the recommendation to use the no-throw version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` will throw an exception if it fails, unless you specify `nothrow`, in which case it will return `nullptr` if it fails.

As for why `nothrow` is ever used: On some systems, exceptions aren't supported (or are badly supported) (this can be particularly true on gaming consoles). So it's best to not even use them at all. This is just one example when `nothrow` may be used.

Comment: The line ` So it's best to not even use them at all.` gives the wrong impression. Maybe you meant ` So it's best to not even use them at all in these systems where exceptions aren't supported or well supported` in continuing with your previous sentence.

Comment: The main reason for using `nothrow` is because you want to handle the error immediately, locally.  A typical example might be in an editor, which will spill to disk (freeing up more memory) if an allocation fails.

Comment: @user93353: yes, that is what I intended with that sentence (I meant it in context of the previous sentence). If it reads otherwise, then thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You could also immediately catch the exception in that situation, in which case it's more of a personal preference then a technical limitation. But personal preference can certainly be a valid reason for using `nothrow`.

Answer (score 2):

> **What about not using `nothrow` argument on `new` operator? Does it also returns `null`?**

The C++ standard (§18.4.1.1) defines operator new as:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
```

So the standard behavior of new which takes one argument is to throw a `std::bad_alloc` in case of failure.
The standard also defines a `nothrow` new version which takes two parameters:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) throw();
```

This version returns a `NULL` in case of failure, but note that to use this version you explicitly need to pass an additional parameter to the new operator.

---

> **When should you use `nothrow` version?**

**Ideally, You should always use the standard version of new which throws a `bad_alloc`**. You should stick to that recommendation always. However, in some situations you might be forced to use the `nothrow` version. Some of such situations are:

- You are working with older C++ compilers (released before the language was standardized) which do not support exceptions.
- The target platforms where exceptions are explicitly disabled (ex: embedded systems) or not guaranteed to work correctly.
- Post 1990's the standard behavior of `new` was to return `NULL`, if you are working with a lot of legacy code which relies on this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

When `new` is not able to allocate memory it throws an exception `bad_alloc` which will make your program to crash in an unusual way if this exception is not handled.If we want avoid this situation we can either use `nothrow` which is the argument for the overloaded function `new` or can catch the exception. `nothrow` will return `null` when out of memory and the programmer can  decide what to do at this point.

Comment: *"The `new` on not able to allocate the memory simply terminates on exception `bad_alloc` which makes our program to crash in an unusual way"*, is Incorrect.Your program will not crash if you catch the exception appropriately. There is nothing unusual it is well defined behavior.If you are using any function/operator which might throw an exception then You should catch the exceptions they are supposed to throw.

Comment: But it will crash if the exception have not been handled. I have said this in the case if there is no exception handling.  "the memory simply terminates on exception bad_alloc " this clearly says that there is an exception which must be handle otherwise program will crash.

Comment: I am sorry but I really cant see how *"the memory simply terminates on exception bad_alloc"* means *"that there is an exception which must be handle otherwise program will crash"*.Both are pretty much orthogonal.

Comment: Edited my answer i hope it can be better understood now.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more clearer, but still the underlying reasoning doesnt go well with me.In case of normal `new` you need to catch exception while in case of `nothrow` `new` you need to check for `null`. In either case, the user of `new` needs to do handle the error condition.So how is `nothrow` any better than normal `new`? It doesn't give you any additional advantage per se.So the reasoning mentioned in your answer is fundamentally flawed and is not enough to advocate `nothrow` over normal `new`.

Comment: Please read the question again. And my answer does not says that not-throw is better than normal. It just explains the difference between them and the outcomes of both scenarios. which is pretty much explained.