# How to use dynamic data structures like std::vector and prevent paging ?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, data-structures, out-of-memory

Following up on this question [Vector push_back only if enough memory is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547294/vector-push-back-only-if-enough-memory-is-available), I tried
to rephrase the question in a more general sense.

Consider this fragment :

```
vector<double> v1;
cout << "pushing back ..." << endl;
while (true) {
    try {
        v1.push_back(0.0);
    } catch (bad_alloc& ba){
        cout << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Which of the following statements regarding the above code fragment are true ?

1) Eventually, the catch block will be reached

2) You can not determine beforehand if there is enough memory for `push_back` to not throw `bad_alloc`

3) Every action in the catch block that involves memory allocation could fail, because there is no memory left

The first thing I did was to run this program on Windows which lead to the observation that before any paging happened, bad_alloc was thrown because obviously the per process amount of memory had been exceeded. This observation lead to the next statement :

4) On most Operating Systems `bad_alloc` will be thrown before paging happens, but there is no certain way to tell beforehand.

After some research I came up with the following thoughts on the above statements :

A1) True, the catch block will be reached but maybe not before the OS has performed intensive I/O operations due to paging.

A2) True, at least not in an OS independent way

A3) True, you have to preallocate memory in order to do something useful with data in the vector gathered so far (e.g. do some paging on your own, if you find this useful)

A4) True, this is dependent on multiple OS-specific parameters like max amount of RAM per process, process priority, strategy of the OS process scheduler etc ...

I am not sure if A1-A4 are correct, hence my question, but if so, here is the next statement :

5) If you need to write some algorithm and be sure that there will be no paging, do not use dynamic data structures like `std::vector`. Instead use an Array and make sure it will stay in memory using OS-specific functions like for example `mlockall` (Unix)

If 5) is true it leads to the last statement :

6) There is no OS-independent way to write a program that will not cause paging.

Thanks everybody in advance for sharing your thoughts on the above statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, 2, and 3 are all correct, assuming that 2 refers to portable ways. You *can* make a decent guess based on OS-specific process memory usage reporting functions. They're not *that* accurate and they're not portable, but they do offer a fairly good guess.

As for 4, that's just not true. It is a function of the amount of physical memory compared to the virtual address space size of the process. x64 has a way larger address space than there is physical memory. x86 is substantially smaller now but go back a few years to older machines with 2GB or 1GB of RAM and it would be bigger.

> If you need to write some algorithm and be sure that there will be no
>   paging, do not use dynamic data structures like std::vector. Instead
>   use an Array and make sure it will stay in memory using OS-specific
>   functions like for example mlockall (Unix)

Bullshit. You can reserve the vector to allocate all the memory you need, then call `mlock` anyway.

But there is most certainly no OS-independent way to write a program that will not cause paging. Paging is an implementation detail of the flat memory model used by C++ and there is certainly no Standard functionality relating to this implementation detail, nor will there ever be.

Comment: I agree, the OS will take care of the memory allocation for you and will decide to do paging without ever telling you and it's completely OS-specific.

Comment: 1) was "Eventually, the catch block will be reached", and you say "1, 2, and 3 are all correct"... that's false as I explain in my answer.

Comment: Such an implementation is non-conforming.

Comment: @Puppy: probably, but Angle.Bracket is clearly interested in what (if anything) can be done to handle this scenario in a practical way, not whether the Standard glosses over it.

Comment: There's a big difference between implementation details, and straight up non-conformance.

Comment: Welcome to the real world. ;-P

Answer (score 2):

If your program must run on Windows/Unix/OS X make a wrapper functions:

```
bool lockMemoryRegion( void *addr, size_t size )
{
#ifdef WIN32
    return VirtualLock( addr, size ) != 0;
#else
    return mlock( addr, size ) == 0;
#endif
}

bool unlockMemoryRegion( void *addr, size_t size )
{
#ifdef WIN32
    return VirtualUnlock( addr, size ) != 0;
#else
    return munlock( addr, size ) == 0;
#endif
}
```

Then if you need to lock memory used by `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v( 1000 );
lockMemoryRegion( v.data(), v.capacity() * sizeof (int) );
```

Use memory locks  only if you really ought to. Locking pages into memory may degrade the performance of the system by reducing the available RAM and forcing the system to swap out other critical pages to the paging file.

Answer (score 1):

What a rambling mess of a question.  You still need to get your head around modern memory allocation on the operating systems you're actually interested in.  I'd recommend a bit of systematic background reading, as answers to your hodge-podge of questions won't necessarily give you the proper big picture.

> 1) Eventually, the catch block will be reached
>
> 2) You can not determine beforehand if there is enough memory for push_back to not throw bad_alloc
>
> 3) Every action in the catch block that involves memory allocation could fail, because there is no memory left

None of these are necessarily true... the OS may allocate the virtual address space then terminate the process when it's accessed and the OS can't find physical memory to back it.  Further, a low-memory process killer may decide you've pushed too far and terminate you or any other non-critical process.

For 3) specifically, the Standard explicitly says an implementation may use a separate memory area to convey the thrown object towards the catch statement that will handle it - after all, it doesn't makes sense to put in on the same stack you're unwinding during exception processing.  So, that memory allocation has much less issues than dynamic memory allocation (with new or malloc) but may still page and therefore precipitate process termination in very rare cases.  It's still dangerous is the object being thrown internally does dynamic memory allocation (e.g. stores a description in a string or istringstream data member).  Similarly, the catch statement may allocate stack space for variables,  expression evaluations, function calls etc. - they could also precipitate failure but are less dangerous than new/malloc.

> 4) On most Operating Systems bad_alloc will be thrown before paging happens, but there is no certain way to tell beforehand.

Certainly not - what would be the point of paging then?

> A1) True, the catch block will be reached but maybe not before the OS has performed intensive I/O operations due to paging.

If there happens to be swap disk in use, then yes you should get paging happening before an out of memory condition, but again that may not manifest as an exception.

> A2) True, at least not in an OS independent way

Nope... it wasn't true to begin with.

> A3) True, you have to preallocate memory in order to do something useful with data in the vector gathered so far (e.g. do some paging on your own, if you find this useful)

You don't have to preallocate anything... which would be done with a constructor parameter or resize... that's optional, but may allow you to process more data without hitting an out of memory condition simply because there's less need for momentarily increased memory usage as the data is moved to a larger memory block.  All that has nothing to do with whether you "do something useful", and I have no idea what you imagine by "do some paging on your own".  If you access vector elements they may have to be paged in.  If you haven't used them for a while they may be paged out.  The OS caching algorithms decide this.  You may want to at least understand a simple algorithm of this type, such as Least Recently Used (LRU).

> A4) True, this is dependent on multiple OS-specific parameters like max amount of RAM per process, process priority, strategy of the OS process scheduler etc ...

You can have a per-process memory allocation limit, but your conception that paging won't happen until you exceed that limit is wrong.  Paging can happen to any part of your process - dynamically allocated, stack, executable image, static data, thread-specific data etc. - whenever the OS sees it hasn't been used for a while and wants the physical memory for some other more pressing purpose.

Your question makes it clear the following suppositions are conditional on the truth of the earlier ones, but I'll address them quickly as they have elements of truth and/or relevance anyway....

> 5) If you need to write some algorithm and be sure that there will be no paging, do not use dynamic data structures like std::vector. Instead use an Array and make sure it will stay in memory using OS-specific functions like for example mlockall (Unix)

Which type of data type/container you use is irrelevant - the OS doesn't even know or care to what use you're putting different parts of the memory it's granted your process.  So, functions like that can be applied to arrays or dynamically allocated memory - for example - if you've populated a vector then you can use .data() to get a pointer to the actual memory region storing data, then lock it into physical RAM.  Of course, if you do something to force the vector to find a different memory region (e.g. adding elements beyond capacity()) then it will still look for more memory and having some deleted memory region locked in physical memory may adversely affect your process and system performance.

> If 5) is true it leads to the last statement :
>
> 6) There is no OS-independent way to write a program that will not cause paging.

No, there's not.  Paging is meant to be transparent to the processes undergoing it, and processes rarely need to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Eventually, the catch block will be reached

This "eventually" doesn't mean "when you allocate up to  bytes" but a lot more (virtual memory mapping - if present - would have to be exhausted as well).

I've seen a linux process scheduler about ten years ago had a habbit of killing applications that misbehaved. I think this application would qualify (i.e. it may be terminated by the OS before the catch block is reached).

> 3) Every action in the catch block that involves memory allocation could fail, because there is no memory left

Theoretically true, practically, probably false. The vector will keep allocating larger and larger contiguous blocks. As it does, it is possible it will no longer be able to allocate a LARGE block, but the previous smaller allocations have been released. It it possible that you will have some free memory available in the catch block.

4) On most Operating Systems bad_alloc will be thrown before paging happens, but there is no certain way to tell beforehand.

Since there is no way to tell beforehand, the only realistic way to find out is to measure it.

> 5) If you need to write some algorithm and be sure that there will be no paging, do not use dynamic data structures like std::vector. Instead use an Array and make sure it will stay in memory using OS-specific functions like for example mlockall (Unix)

This is incorrect. A vector is a safe wrapper on an allocated contiguous memory block. You can just as well work with a vector and memory locking functions.

For (6): Paging is HW, OS and application dependent (you can run the same application on two different systems and have it paged differently).