# how do I know if set.insert() failed due to not enough memory in C++?

Tags: c++, set

I am running a very large case simulation that failed in `set.insert()`. I suspect that it failed due to not enough memory. Can the return value of `set.insert()` tell me that the failure is due to not enough memory for holding the set?

Comment: Let's say you can do this. May I ask what you plan on doing with this information? Do you hope to recover from this somehow? If your set is holding a small type, e.g. `int`, there's not really much you can do.

Comment: I guess you'll probably get an exception.  What error message are you seeing? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: On memory error, it should throw bad_alloc, that you may catch.

Comment: Well. I am debugging this case for my customer. If the failure is due to not enough memory, I can tell my customer that the machine you using is not having enough memory to run such a simulation.

Comment: It will throw an exception.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749066/how-to-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-c) carefully. Especially the bits about what you'll need to do if you want to recover *programmatically*.

Comment: *I suspect that it failed due to not enough memory* -- Until you verify this, I suggest not jumping to conclusions that it is a lack of memory being the reason for the error.

Comment: @cigien The difficulty of recovering from `std::bad_alloc` is often overstated. If you're allocating a little here and a little there and that fails, sure, you are in trouble. It probably means you are on an embedded system and you are just asking too much of the hardware. But `std::bad_alloc` on a desktop or server environment is almost guaranteed to be caused by asking for way too much memory and throwing `std::bad_alloc` will simply unwind the stack and free up all the memory you've managed to accumuate so far for the task. Just don't try to `catch` it on the spot.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, I did mention small allocations in the first comment. It's not clear what issue the OP is trying to solve though, so I pointed it out :)

Comment: Fun fact: Windows by default comes with an unlimited swap file. "Out-of-memory" conditions are often never reached because the program appears "frozen" long before due to constant paging and is killed by the user.